# How to implement: Track an item through processes with a linked document?

Tags: approval-process, records-management, links, document-management

I'm looking for the best way to implement a system in SharePoint to track processes during asset production which includes document management for the asset itself. Let me try to break down the problem in simple terms:

Say we have a Product which needs three assets, Asset A, Asset B, and Asset C. The Product has its own project subsite. All assets are documents which go through various (different) stages of production. The Product is only complete once all Assets are present and have completed their processes 100%.

Looking at Asset A, there are certain known data and processes to be logged before the document/asset itself exists. The title is known before the document is created, and a "Commissioning" process must be initiated as a task and tracked with dates. Once Commissioning is complete, the document Asset A needs to be uploaded and linked to the title and commissioning information, then the next process "Proofing" needs to be tracked. Asset A's production could be said to be 33% complete after Commissioning, 66% complete after the document is uploaded, and 100% complete after Proofing.

My current thinking of how to achieve this is to create a list to hold the Asset records' key information, including that which is known before the document is created. Then the document is uploaded to the project document library and linked to the Asset record. I am unsure whether a task list for the processes would need to be separate or if it can also be integrated with the Asset record list.

Please can someone suggest the best way to organise this information in SharePoint. Should it be a separate Asset list to hold record information and track the production progress, or can all of this be incorporated within document metadata? Or should the whole process be represented as a task list?

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks!
Mark.